# Create resource group with azure policy in each subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to create an Azure policy for creating a RG for every subscription under my tenant.
I created this custom policy like I saw in some example but nothing is being created.

The custom policy:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Create resource group if not exists",
        "description": "This policy will create resource group if not exists",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "All",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "category": "Resource Management"
        },
        "parameters": {},
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
                "details": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
                    "name": "createResourceGroup",
                    "roleDefinitionIds": [
                        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
                    ],
                    "existenceCondition": {
                        "field": "name",
                        "equals": "TestRG"
                    },
                    "deployment": {
                        "properties": {
                            "mode": "incremental",
                            "template": {
                                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                                "contentVersion": "",
                                "parameters": {},
                                "variables": {},
                                "resources": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
                                        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
                                        "name": "TestRG",
                                        "location": "eastus",
                                        "tags": {
                                            "Test": "Infra"
                                        },
                                        "properties": {}
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "parameters": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas I would really appreciate that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The alias "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions" which you are referring to does not exist within the available aliases, hence the custom policy isn't working as expected. You can verify the list of available aliases using the PowerShell command "[Get-AzPolicyAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicyalias?view=azps-8.3.0)".

To raise a new policy alias request, you need to create ticket with Microsoft Support team.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Azure Policy that checks for the existence of a resource group named ‘myResourceGroup’ within the specified subscription. If it does not find such a group, it flags this as non-compliance. A Remediation task can be created, which, when executed, will create the resource group for you.

```
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "field": "type",
    "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions"
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
    "details": {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/Subscriptions/resourcegroups",
      "roleDefinitionIds": [
        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
      ],
      "evaluationDelay": "AfterProvisioning",
      "existenceCondition": {
        "field": "name",
        "equals": "myResourceGroup"
      },
      "resourceGroupName": "myResourceGroup",
      "deploymentScope": "subscription",
      "deployment": {
        "location": "westeurope",
        "properties": {
          "mode": "incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {},
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [
              {
                "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
                "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
                "name": "myResourceGroup",
                "location": "westeurope",
                "properties": {}
              }
            ],
            "outputs": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"parameters": {}}
```